# Match a string satisfying other two strings

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex patters which will return true when my string exactly matched with the strings in regex patters.

The below is my conditions,

My Word : "email" or "sms"

Conditions :

- given string "email" - regex should return true;
- given string "sms" - regex should return true;
- given string as "emails" - regex should return false
- given string as "smss" - regex should return false;
- given string as "sm s" or "ema il" - regex should return false;
- given string as "test" - regex should return false;
- given string as "test email test" - regex should return false;

Comment: Which engine, which flavor?

Comment: I need this to run in php laravel,

Comment: Not sure about php laravel, but generally, this should work: `\b(email|sms)\b`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but when I enter "test email test" - the regex should return false.

Comment: Then use this: `^\b(email|sms)\b$`

Comment: exactly wht I expected. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, I'm not sure about php laravel but this regex should have the principal components regardless of engine/flavor to produce the matches you want:

```
^\b(email|sms)\b$
```

Comment: Glad it worked though I'm really not familiar with php laravel.